# How to disable moving down on Enter key in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

When entering data in a cell and pressing enter, the cursor moves down one step. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel menu > Preferences ... > Edit

There is a checkbox for "After pressing RETURN, move selection", then a dropdown menu for "Down; Up; Right; Left".

If you deselect the checkbox you will remain in the current cell.

If you keep the checkbox selected but choose a different menu option you can move in a different direction.